# Using Salesforce as Single Source of Truth

Tags: data, design-patterns, architecture

From a software architecture perspective, are there major issues with using Salesforce as an application's single source of truth (as opposed to a traditional relational database like Postgres)?

It seems to have a lot of benefits. Most notably, our CX representatives can directly edit Client and related record data without us having to working about synching that data on the tech side. I wonder if there are drawbacks though.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is a very broad question. What you want is definitely possible but the possibility of doing so greatly depend on the details of what you require. I'll try to give you some things to consider.

- Salesforce runs on a shared architecture. This means it has a lot of [governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#!), which can make processing your data complicated.
- Data storage is expensive compared to other data storage providers.
- Salesforce doesn't handle data skew well. If you have a data structure that requires many child records to a parent record you may have to solve that in complicated ways. (The limit is I believe 10.000 child records to one parent.)
- There are certain things you simply can't do on the platform (like image manipulation).
- There may be dedicated software which is hard to replace within Salesforce. Think for instance of something simple as an email client. It's definitely possible to sync that kind of information, but then the source of truth may not be Salesforce.

If Salesforce is the basis of many of your company's processes then what you want may well be possible and desirable. If you want specific advice on your situation you may need to be more specific.

Comment: N.B. accountancy software can be addressed with Financial Force which runs on SFDC platform

Comment: Thanks @cropredy, I thought Financial Force was only build for the United States tax code, but they seem to be selling internationally.